# Export millions records into excel from postgresql in spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, query-performance, jdbctemplate

I am using Apache poi jar and using SXSSFWorkbook interface to export million records into excel in spring boot java. Moreover I am using jdbc template (fetchSize) and rowcallbackhandler to get the records from database (postgresql) in chunks however it looks like records are still being fetched from db in one shot. Please suggest, below is the code which I m using to fetch from db

```
   jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(1000);
   jdbcTemplate.query("select * from tbl",new 
                                     RowCallBackHandler(ResultSet rs){
                                           // Create row in excel and write data
                                      }
                                   );
```

Comment: If your requirement is fetch the data and write it to excel. You can use Spring batch where you can read and write the data in the batches. With this system will use less resources while reading and writing operations.

Answer (score -1):

In a similiar java code I'm using  I have to set

setAutoCommit(false);

in the connection, for fetch to work properly.

```
       conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);
       conn1.setAutoCommit(false); 
       ...
        pstatement1 = conn1.prepareStatement(sqlsel);
        pstatement1.setString(1, sistema);
        pstatement1.setInt(2, id);
        pstatement1.setFetchSize(100);
```

good luck!
and if this don't solve the problem add JAVA version info in your question and also the driver version.

Comment: In spring boot the JDBC related boiler plate code is not needed. It has data starters like `data-jdbc` or `data-jpa`.  But still getting 1M records will be challenge itself.